# Почему ОБНЕСТИ – это УКРАСТЬ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, тире, дефис

Выполнял сегодня упражнение "П(п)опа(–)-листик" из этого ролика: https://youtube.com/shorts/hnFnYnWPXyA?feature=share4

Возникли такие вопросы:

1. Название упражнения с большой или с маленькой буквы писать надо не в начале предложения?
2. После "попа" и перед "листик" нужны ли пробелы?
3. Между "попа" и "листик" стоит дефис или тире?
4. Почему "обнести" – это украсть?

Comment: У меня один вопрос: за что?

Comment: @Аким Табурет По поводу"листика". Разве здесь есть варианты письма? (Впрочем, как и  произношения тоже.)  Тогда о чем спрашивать?

Comment: @Sharon Есть варианты. Дефис — когда единое понятие. А здесь как: *руки — ноги* (сначала руки, а потом ноги).

Comment: Варианты-то есть, да не все походят к этой теме. Автор, вероятно, это знает. Однако, вопрос закрыли.